# How is the `dict` attribute processed internally?

Tags: vimscript

If I source:

```
let Mydict = { 'data': [0, 1, 2, 3] }
fu! Mydict.mylen()
    return len(self.data)
endfu
```

Then, I can execute `echo Mydict.mylen()` which returns `4` because it's the length of the list `[0,1,2,3]`. I didn't have to give the `dict` attribute to the function `Mydict.mylen()`.

---

If I source:

```
fu! MyFunc() dict
    return len(self.data)
endfu
let mydict = { 'data': [0, 1, 2, 3], 'mylen': function('MyFunc') }
```

Then, I can execute `echo mydict.mylen()` which, again, returns `4`, for the same reason as before. However, this time, I had to give the `dict` attribute to the function `MyFunc()`. Without `dict`, it would have raised the errors:

```
E121: Undefined variable: self
E116: Invalid arguments for function len(self.data)
E15: Invalid expression: len(self.data)
```

---

If I source:

```
fu! Order() dict
    echo 'eat your ' . self.name
endfu
let food       = { 'name': 'vegetables' }
let BuildOrder = function('Order', food)
```

Then, I can execute `call BuildOrder()`, which displays `eat your vegetables`. I had to give the `dict` attribute to the function `Order()`, for the same reason as before.

---

If I source:

```
fu! Describe(count, adj) dict
    echo a:count.' '.a:adj.' '. self.name
endfu
let animal      = { 'name': 'piggies' }
let Description = function('Describe', [ 3 ], animal)
```

Then, I can execute `call Description('little')`, which displays `3 little piggies`. And again, I had to give the `dict` attribute to the `Describe()` function.

---

`dict` is only needed in the last 3 of the 4 previous snippets. What does Vim do internally, which explains that `dict` is not needed in the first one, but is in all the others?

And whatever it does, why doesn't it do it in the last 3 snippets? What would happen if it did it all the time, or never?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is described at [`:help Dictionary-function`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#Dictionary-function):

```
                *Dictionary-function* *self* *E725* *E862*
When a function is defined with the "dict" attribute it can be used in a
special way with a dictionary.  Example: >
    :function Mylen() dict
    :   return len(self.data)
    :endfunction
    :let mydict = {'data': [0, 1, 2, 3], 'len': function("Mylen")}
    :echo mydict.len()

This is like a method in object oriented programming.  The entry in the
Dictionary is a |Funcref|.  The local variable "self" refers to the dictionary
the function was invoked from.

It is also possible to add a function without the "dict" attribute as a
Funcref to a Dictionary, but the "self" variable is not available then.

                *numbered-function* *anonymous-function*
To avoid the extra name for the function it can be defined and directly
assigned to a Dictionary in this way: >
    :let mydict = {'data': [0, 1, 2, 3]}
    :function mydict.len()
    :   return len(self.data)
    :endfunction
    :echo mydict.len()

The function will then get a number and the value of dict.len is a |Funcref|
that references this function.  The function can only be used through a
|Funcref|.  It will automatically be deleted when there is no |Funcref|
remaining that refers to it.
```

Both approaches define a function which will have access to their containing dict via the name `self`.

The `function mydict.len` approach is just syntactic sugar to define the functions directly in the dictionary.  You can still assign that function to other dictionaries:

```
:let otherdict = { 'data': [0, 1], 'len': function(mydict.len) }
:echo otherdict.len()
2
```